# Insert Tomorrows Date at Specific Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am attempting to insert tomorrow's date at 10:00:00 into SQL Server 2005/2008.

I currently have

```
DATEADD(dd, 1, GETDATE())
```

which gives me tomorrow's date fine, however I have tried a number of methods to also concat / set the time to `10:00:00`.

Example:

```
Current Time: 2013-01-07 15:37:05
Required Insert Date: 2013-01-08 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`.

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh,10, DATEDIFF(dd,0, DATEADD(dd, 1, GetDate())))
```

`DATEDIFF(dd,0...)` truncates the time part of a date, hence "rounds" to midnight and `DATEADD(hh,10...)` adds 10 hours.

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1881/0)

Comment: Thanks! You can also do GetDate()+1 instead of DATEADD(dd, 1, GetDate()) to shorten it up a bit

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

`DATEADD(hh,34,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()))`

Answer (score 1):

One less `DATEADD` than the other answers:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-02T10:00:00')
```

This adds the (integral) number of days since 1st January 2001 onto 10am on the 2nd January 2001.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yep, corrected in my edit as I added explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Oracle - returns 10 a.m. of next day:

```
Select to_char((trunc(Sysdate)+1)+10/24, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:ss:mi') insert_date
 From dual
 /

 SQL> 2013-01-08 10:00:00
```